# Copying file using Scanner Class java

Tags: java

I am trying to copy content of textfile.txt to target.txt using the Scanner Class.

When I run the program it does create the target.txt file but it doesn't write to it.

I can use FileInputStream and copy the file but i want to use the Scanner Class.

Can anyone see what i am doing wrong?

thanks.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadaFile {

    public ReadaFile() throws IOException {

        try {

            File f1 = new File("textfile.txt");
            File f2 = new File("target.txt");

            Scanner in = new Scanner(f1);
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f2);

            byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
            int i = 0;

            while (in.hasNextByte()) {

                if (in.hasNextByte() && i < buf.length) {
                    buf[i] = in.nextByte();
                    i++;
                }else{
                    out.write(buf, 0, i);
                    out.flush();
                }

            }

            in.close();
            out.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new ReadaFile();

    }

}
```

Comment: Are you using Java 7? Then just use `File.copy`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29

Comment: Or if you're not, just use `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream`. Using `Scanner` is an odd choice here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not use a buffer array at all. You could directly write it bytes like this(as you insist on using a Scanner, thus this solution)

```
while (in.hasNext()) {
    out.write(in.nextLine().getBytes());
    out.write("\n".getBytes()); // This will write an extra new line character at the end of all the data.
    out.flush();
}
```

Comment: thanks R.J, I have tried your suggestion but still doing the same. it create target.txt file but it doesn't write to it.

Comment: @user2995057 - I tried this code in my system and it worked. It was only after that, did I post it as an answer itself.

Comment: Thank R.J, Sorry mate i still had condition of the While loop (in.hasNextByte()) i changed it to (in.hasNext()) as you suggested and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Scanner is designated to parse text data. So it's hasNextByte and nextByte methods supposed to get numbers from file and convert them to bytes.
If you want to obtain a text from file you could use FileReader.